# How to compile and link separated .h and .cpp files in C++ using the command line?

Tags: c++, g++

I wanted to separate function definitions and function headers using folders but I get a fatal error saying "x.h" was not found. The filenames provided below are just samples. Is this even possible?

This is the line I'm using:

```
g++ -I ./headers/ -o main2.o main2.cpp ./definitions/x.cpp
```

Comment: can you describe what your source directory layout is?

Comment: main2.cpp is in the parent directory while headers/ and definitions/ are sub-directories of this parent directory, say, solver/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're sure you've correct files in correct path, one issue is :-

There shouldn't be any space after `-I` and use just `./headers`

```
g++ -I./headers -o main2.o main2.cpp ./definitions/x.cpp 
      ^^No Space
```

Comment: `-Iheaders` should be sufficient. Both instances of `./` are redundant.

Comment: @MarceloCantos, this is true, but I find it's quite useful in practice to draw a larger visual distinction between `-I./pathoflibrary` and `-lnameoflibrary` and a `./` is a very good way to do that. :)

Comment: g++ does not complain when there's a space between `-I` and `folderPath/`. Even without a space, it works too. Both seem to work fine. I prefer readability over shortcuts (well, except file paths. hello symlinks).

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity: That's a good point, though I have to say that I've never once encountered this problem in practice.